# How long should it take to clone the cpython hg repository?

Tags: mercurial

Last night, I tried to clone the cpython hg repo, but after ~ 30 min. of waiting, I cancelled, because it didn't seem to be working. Based on process time, it seemed to be doing hardly anything. Was I simply too impatient? Or should hg clone be pretty fast?

I'd just downloaded the latest hg:

```
$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.5.4+20130405)
```

I ran this on Mac OSX 10.8.3.

I was using a good Internet connection: Comcast Business Class over WiFi, with the wireless router under my desk.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should take < 5 min.

```
$ time hg clone http://hg.python.org/cpython python-repo-2
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 83508 changesets with 184511 changes to 9865 files (+1 heads)
updating to branch default
3677 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

real    3m11.586s
user    1m44.192s
sys 0m6.959s
```

I'm pretty sure I waited longer than that last night. Maybe the repo was experiencing high traffic last night, but everything is OK today? I am using a different Internet connection today, so it could be that.

Hopefully, someone finds this one data point to be useful.

Comment: The only thing to add is that you should enable the [progress extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ProgressExtension) to get more feedback for long-running operations.